# How does Firebase Analytics track it's automatic events?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-broadcast, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics tracks a number of default events: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485

Some of them like

- first_open
- app_remove
- app_clear_data
- app_update

are BroadcastIntents that don't get sent to the affected package. ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH is for example only sent to the installer package, not to the package being installed ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH)).

How does Firebase Analytics still manage to track these events? What's their method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`first_open` and `app_update` are base on data stored on disk. Each time Firebase Analytics start it reads stored state on disk and checks if this is the first time the app runs. If that's the case `first_open` event is recorded and the state on disk is updated. `app_upgrade` works similarly. When Firebase Analytics starts is check the version of the app when it last have seen it running. If the version differs it logs `app_update` event and updates the state on disk. Where the state on disk is kept differs between devices with and without Google Play Services. On devices with the service the state is saved within Google Play Services data. On non-Google Play devices the data is saved with the app.

`app_clear_data` and `app_remove` work only on devices with Google Play Services (most Android devices). The Firebase Service that record the state on disk runs inside Google Play Services so when the app runs there is code in the app that tells the Google Play Services if its shared preference file stored in the app data was deleted. Google Play Services then check if this app has run in the past and if it has run it then assumes the app data was cleared and logs `app_clear_data`.

For `app_remove` there is broadcast from [Package Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) when a package is removed. Google Play Services listens to this broadcast and when it receives it `app_remove` event is recorded and all data related to this app is removed from the device.

Comment: Thanks! I am accepting this answer as I guess it will be right :) No way of verifying it

Comment: Is there also a way to turn off all automatic analytics events? Such as "first_open", "session_start", etc... we have our own system and do not want the additional noise. Thanks.

Comment: From where you have those information how they measure app_clear_data ? Your answer how they do it is silly. It is more easy to listen for system event eg. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED